# Interlaced tables terminology

Tags: database, csv, terminology

I am looking for the correct term to describe the following way of storing tables. Consider Table 1 `(user_id, name, year)` and Table 2 `(price, timestamp)`. Some particular data is stored for each table, but in one CSV file in the order of insertion, e.g.:

```
10,mary,2005
12,john,2018
1350,1569668115
38,lucy,2009
1400,1569669115
```

Even though the tables are not related, they are stored in one file in this fashion. Is there a name for this? I tried searching for *interlaced*, which gave me no relevant results and *interleaved* and *nested tables*, which means something else completely.

**Note:** The actual file contains a column, which distinguishes the rows:

```
T1,10,mary,2005
T1,12,john,2018
T2,1350,1569668115
T1,38,lucy,2009
T2,1400,1569669115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"interleaved" would be my first guess, but I don't think there is a standard term for this.  maybe you could could add some more detail/context to the question

I tend to associate "interlaced" with display and images, with Google saying:

> (of a video image) scanned in such a way that alternate lines form one sequence which is followed by the other lines in a second sequence.

so not much to do with data.  while "nested" implies a inner/outer parent/child relationship, while your tables seem unrelated (or at least you don't give a way to link records).

for "interleaved" I get:

> mix (digital signals) by alternating between them.

which seems appropriate, but I see use of the term in [cockroachdb](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/interleave-in-parent.html) that you might feel is inappropriate.

that said, and given that you're seeing this in a CSV file, this usage seems more like "logging", maybe for security or auditing purposes.  some databases also do this, see the [WAL in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html) and similar things exist in many other highly available systems, but probably not to a CSV file.